# How is the price of a magic weapon or armor determined if it's enhanced some more later?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm not sure my phrasing is the best so let me try an example;

I have a masterwork dagger (valued at 302 gp) and I decide to get it enhanced with a +1.

That would mean I pay 2,000 gp and the dagger is now worth 2,302 gp.

I now want the dagger to have a total enhancement of +3.  Do I pay the base price of 18,000 gp or the base price minus what I already payed, making it 16,000 gp?

Similarly, let's say I have another masterwork dagger and wish to get a +5 on it right away.  Do I just pay the base price of 50,000 gp?